# Passing parameter to custom Gradle task

Tags: gradle, plugins, gradlew

I've written simple custom Gradle task that extends `DefaultTask` and does some action and I would like to pass it some parameter(s) using command line. At the bottom is code for adding task to list of available tasks and "implementation" of the task.

Now, when I execute: `./gradlew customTask -PcustomParam="value"` how can I retrieve `customParam` value in `doAction` method?

```
project.tasks.create("customTask", CustomTask::class.java
```

---

```kotlin
open class CustomTask : DefaultTask() {
  @TaskAction
  fun doAction() {
    // retrieve passed parameter
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (project.hasProperty('customParam')) {
    println project.property('customParam')
}
```

@see [project.property(String name)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#property%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Well, thank you :) I've done that before and for some reason got build error (since whole build includes library and android app) and now it's fine. Error was something like: There is no property "customParam" for task

Comment: My example contains an `if` condition which should avoid this exception. Without the `hasProperty` check an exception will be thrown when the parameter is not provided